# What is the difference b/w @form value and explicitly mentioning the component Ids in render attribute of <f:ajax>?

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, jsf-2.2, mojarra

Consider the snippet:

```
<h:form>                                  
    <hr/>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                Name:
        <h:inputText id="nameId" value="#{ajaxBean.name}" 
                     validator="nameValidator" 
                     f5:placeholder="Enter your name ..."/>
        <h:message id="msgNameId" showDetail="true" 
                   showSummary="true" for="nameId" 
                   style="color: red;"/>
                Surname:            
        <h:inputText id="surnameId" value="#{ajaxBean.surname}" 
                     validator="nameValidator" 
                     f5:placeholder="Enter your surname ..."/>
        <h:message id="msgSurnameId" showDetail="true" 
                   showSummary="true" for="surnameId" 
                   style="color: red;"/>            
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton value="Submit">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" 
                        render="@form" listener="#
                        {ajaxBean.upperCaseNameAndSurname()}"/  
   </h:commandButton>

   <h:commandButton value="Cancel">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" 
                        render="@form"/>
   </h:commandButton>  
   <h:commandButton value="Clear/Reset">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" 
                        render="@form" 
                        listener="#{ajaxBean.cancelNameAndSurname()}"/> 
   </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

`resetValues= "true"` seems to work only if one mentions the `component ids` *explicitly* inside the `render` attribute of the `<f:ajax>` for the `Submit` button.

i.e `render="nameId msgNameId surnameId msgSurnameId"` rather than `render="@form"`

What exactly is the difference b/w these 2 forms?

The invalid values are still there `after re-render` if the value is `(@form)` for `render` attribute for `Submit` button.

I definitely remembered one of the comments by BalusC,

> When validations phase has failed due to a conversion or validation
>   error anywhere, components which `successfully` passed validation will
>   return `local value` and components which `failed` validation will return
>   `submitted value`.

If the name is valid and the surname is not (or any other combination involving invalid values), then after `submit` and `clear/ reset`, the input field*(i.e the valid field)* for the name is not cleared. Even though the `whole form` was `re-rendered`, I see only the field for which validation failed was cleared. Why?

Does the above comment signifies some relation with the above problem?

The  `cancelNameAndSurname` method just do this thing-

```
name = ""
surname = ""
```

I know for sure that one of the solutions to resolve this is -

```
       <f:actionListener type="org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener"/>
```

Comment: Looks like a Mojarra bug. The `resetValues="true"` is expected to cover all children of `render` too.

Comment: @BalusC: This is taken from the Anghel Leonard's book Chapter 7 where he demonstrates on how to make a Cancel and Clear/ Reset button. He further illustrates the omnifaces eventlistener -ResetInputAjaxActionListener.